Solid rod vs hollow rod in compressive strength
Which one is stronger in compression, a solid rod for example a solid bone without a cavity or a hollow rod like a typical long bone with the same circumference as the solid rod?

"I'm not a stress/structures guy; so I asked a co-worker about it, and he said that the solid rod would be stiffer, because it had the greater (bending) moment of inertia" from the link. Seems like they are talking about bending, not compression

Co-worker is correct for both bending and compression.

All things being equal the solid circular cross-section rod will support a higher load than a hollow circular rod of the same circumference and material.  In the case of pure compression, it's just about material cross-sectional area and nothing else (also see comments below).
However, there are some "buts".  In the real world, rods (and bones) rarely fail in pure compression.  Torsion or bending (combination of compression and tension) are more common failure modes.  Buckling can also be a failure mode.  For bending, torsion, and buckling you get more strength and stiffness per unit of material by placing the material farther away from the neutral (center) axis.  If you care about weight and cost (like most people), then you try design the load-bearing shape to use material optimally.   That's why, for example, I-beams aren't square or circular and it's why bicycle tubes are thin and hollow.
But back to the main question - if you want maximum strength in a fixed circular area and don't care about weight or cost, then yes - solid is the way to go.

Thank you, even at the same weight, the solid rod will be stronger in compression than the hollow rod with the same circumference. Correct?

In pure compression, the only thing that matters is material cross-sectional area.  If they have the same circumference but one is hollow, then they CAN'T have the same weight or cross-sectional area.  If you expand the circumference for the hollow one until they have the same cross-sectional area, then the strength (and weight) is the same.

One extra comment: "compression" can mean two different things.  As a failure mode it describes how the material fails (opposite of tension).  I sort of assumed this definition in my response.  But compression can also be a loading description.  Rods loaded in compression can also fail in "buckling" which is kind of like sideways bending.  In that case, the last sentence I wrote in the above comment is not correct and there is an effect of mass distribution.  But it's still true that for a given radius/diameter/circumference, a solid rod will be the strongest.

Which comment of yours is not correct? Is it this one "If you expand the circumference for the hollow one until they have the same cross-sectional area, then the strength (and weight) is the same."?

Yes.  If you expand the hollow one to have  a larger circumference, it will be stronger in buckling than the solid one.  But in PURE compression they are equally strong.

Let's use the Mariano G answer as the main answer, and start here from the last sentence, very important one, about constraints in structural mechanics and mechanics in general.
For small loads, two beams with the same sections have the same stiffness, and usually don't fail. One of the main failure mechanism for slender beams is buckling, when compression exceeds a certain critical load.
If you want the same weight with the same material, you should go for the hollow one, with reasonable diameter to avoid thin-wall beam instabilities.
The reason why you should go for this configuration is about the critical load for buckling, see column buckling in wikipedia page. The critical load for different configurations of a compressed beam usually is
$$F^{crit} \propto \dfrac{EJ}{L^2} \ ,$$
being $EJ$ the bending stiffness and $L$ a characteristic length of the configuration.
With the hollow configuration with the same area (from the weight constraint), you're moving area from the axis to outer regions, and thus increasing the inertia and the bending stiffness of the beam.
